# Reading subsets of columns of a matrix from a mat file in c

Tags: c, matlab

I have a very large matrix stored in a mat file, and in a C program I need the data stored in the first few columns of it. Currently I read the whole matrix into memory using matGetVariable, but it takes up a lot of memory. I wonder if there is an easy way to read only the first few columns of a matrix, or subinices of a variable, into memory in C.

Comment: If it's a v7.3 mat file, that means it's actually in [hdf5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) format and you can use the hdf5 library to get part of the matrix out. Not sure about older-format matfiles.

Comment: Additionally if you can figure out the file format there is nothing stopping you from reading the raw bytes from the file yourself.

Comment: @Dougal: Thanks! It is actually v7.3 mat file.